# Center button with no label in BottomNavigationBar

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to achieve this bottom navigation bar in Flutter, in which the supposed floating action bar is in the same level as the other items in the navigation bar.

[image]

I tried using this code for the `BottomNavigationBarItem`:

```
  BottomNavigationBarItem(
  icon: Align(
    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
    child: Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.deepPurple, shape: BoxShape.circle),
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(14),
      child: Icon(Icons.add, color: Colors.white),
    ),
  ),
  title: Text("", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 0)),
),
```

But this one gives me an error: [image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `floatingActionButton` with `floatingActionButtonLocation` property of Scaffold :

```
floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(onPressed: () {  },child: Icon(Icons.add),),
```